# Elasticsearch: Index object when Attachment Type is null

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, null, elasticsearch, tire

I'm trying to index a bunch of documents using Elasticsearch & Tire gem. Indexing is working great except in rare cases where the record isn't complete and there is no referenced `filename`. In those cases *nothing* in the record is indexed and Elasticsearch throws a `NullPointerException`.

I don't know Java but wondering if there's a way to pass *something* to the Attachment Type plugin so that Elasticsearch will successfully index the rest of the record and just bypass the `:type => 'attachment'` where `attachment` returns `null`?

Tried `"attachment" : {"type" : "attachment", "null_value" : "missing_file"}` (or in Tire parlance: `indexes :attachment, :type => 'attachment', :null_value => "missing_file"`) but this doesn't appear to make any difference.

```
#app/models/article.rb
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Tire::Model::Search
  include Tire::Model::Callbacks

  attr_accessible :title, :content, :published_on, :filename

  mapping do
    indexes :id, :type =>'integer'
    indexes :title
    indexes :content
    indexes :published_on, :type => 'date'
    indexes :attachment, :type => 'attachment', :null_value => 'missing_file'  # <== no worky
  end

  def to_indexed_json
    to_json(:methods => [:attachment])
  end

  def attachment
    if filename.present?
       path_to_pdf = "/Volumes/HardDisk/sample_pdfs/#{filename}.pdf"
       Base64.encode64(open(path_to_pdf) { |pdf| pdf.read })
    end
  end
end


#Elasticsearch log:
[2012-06-29 09:01:15,515][DEBUG][action.bulk              ] [Skunge the Laxidazian Troll] [articles][4] failed to execute bulk item (index) index {[articles][article][10], source[{"content":"this title is fluff","created_at":"2012-06-27T22:02:43Z","filename":null,"id":10,"published_on":"2012-06-27","title":"Test title","updated_at":"2012-06-27T22:02:43Z","attachment":null}]}
java.lang.NullPointerException
```